# Why .htaccess / Web.Config file is not working on windows server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config

My .htaccess file is all working in localhost. Did I make the site live then there htaccess is not working. And my live server is Windows server not the linux server

I have used this site for htaccess to web config converter [htaccess to webconfig link](http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com/)

**.htacess code**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^index.html$  index.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule  ^enquiry.html$  enquiry.php [NC,QSA]
```

**Web Config Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
<rule name="rule 1o">
    <match url="^index.html$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2o">
    <match url="^enquiry.html$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="enquiry.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think your question is really: "Why is my Web.Config code not working?"

Comment: @w3d If you know that the solution please help me... :)

Comment: I don't know Web.Config (IIS) syntax unfortunately. (I was attracted to your question by the .htaccess reference.) However, your code is not the same as the output from the tool you link to, which includes `url="/enquiry.php"` - you are missing the slash prefix. (?)

Comment: @w3d Hey I got the answer my code Working is fine ..  thanx for helping  for giving me the your important time...

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question if you think other users would find it useful. You can then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have own solve this Bcoz my the IIS 7 is helping me for this and

Your can use the config and rewrite and all rule set in the rules then you got the answer for htaccess is working in webconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="MyRule">
          <match url="index.html" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```